# First occurence of specific value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I missed one layer of complexity which I didn't think was relevant however it appears that is it because the MIN() suggestions don't seem to work with this.

I have a table that looks like:

```
col-1 | col-b | col-c | col-d
----------------------------------
mhm1  | a     | 09:20 | 2013-09-21
mhm1  | b     | 09:21 | 2013-09-20
mhm1  | c     | 09:22 | 2013-09-19
mhm1  | c     | 09:23 | 2013-09-18
mhm1  | d     | 09:24 | 2013-09-19
mhm2  | a     | 09:25 | 2013-09-21
mhm2  | c     | 09:26 | 2013-09-20
mhm2  | d     | 09:27 | 2013-09-19
mhm2  | c     | 09:28 | 2013-09-18
```

I would like a query that returns the 1st row for each unique col-1 where col-b = 'c'.

e.g.

```
col-1 | col-b | col-c | col-d
---------------------------------
mhm1  | c     | 09:23 | 2013-09-18
mhm2  | c     | 09:28 | 2013-09-18
```

What would be the appropiate SQL-Request to achieve this?
I have tried:

```
SELECT col-a, col-b, min(col-c), min(col-d) FROM MY TABLE
WHERE col-b = 'c'
GROUP BY col-a
ORDER BY col-c ASC
```

But I get:

```
col-1 | col-b | col-c | col-d
---------------------------------
mhm1  | c     | 09:22 | 2013-09-18
mhm2  | c     | 09:26 | 2013-09-18
```

Which is not what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the [MIN() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) you tell MySQL, that you want the lowest value in that group.

```
SELECT col-a, col-b, MIN(col-c) FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE col-b = 'c'
GROUP BY col-a
/* ORDER BY col-c ASC <-- this is not necessary*/
```

This will work in your example. But it can be dangerous. The other columns values don't need to belong to that row with the minimum col-c value. To achieve that, you'd have to write it as follows:

```
SELECT col-a, col-b, col-c FROM MY_TABLE t
WHERE col-b = 'c'
AND col-c = (SELECT MIN(col-c) FROM yourTable yt WHERE yt.col-a = t.col-a)
GROUP BY col-a
```

For more examples see this [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [**`MIN()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min)function to col-c to achieve this

```
SELECT col-1, col-b, MIN(col-c)
FROM MY TABLE
WHERE col-b = 'c'
GROUP BY col-1
ORDER BY col-c ASC
```

#### [Live SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7242/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_test;

CREATE TABLE my_test (col1 CHAR(4) NOT NULL,colb CHAR(1) NOT NULL,colc TIME NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(col1,colb,colc));

INSERT INTO my_test VALUES
('mhm1','a','09:20:00'),
('mhm1','b','09:21:00'),
('mhm1','c','09:22:00'),
('mhm1','c','09:23:00'),
('mhm1','d','09:24:00'),
('mhm2','a','09:25:00'),
('mhm2','c','09:26:00'),
('mhm2','d','09:27:00'),
('mhm2','c','09:28:00');

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_test x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT col1,colb,MIN(colc) min_colc FROM my_test GROUP BY col1,colb) y 
    ON y.col1 = x.col1 
   AND y.colb=x.colb 
   AND y.min_colc = x.colc 
WHERE x.colb = 'c';
+------+------+----------+
| col1 | colb | colc     |
+------+------+----------+
| mhm1 | c    | 09:22:00 |
| mhm2 | c    | 09:26:00 |
+------+------+----------+
```